# Looking for convenient way of converting space separated ASCII numbers to letters in Shell

Tags: shell

I want to convert `104 101 108 108 111` to `hello` string in Shell without using any external tool. What would be the convenient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There a function that'll help:

```bash
chr() {
    printf "\x$(printf "%x" "$1")"
}
```

```bash
chr 65    # => A
```

Comment: I want multiple space separated ASCII numbers to be converted to letters at once. Using that function would require me to do it character by character, so it's not really convenient, especially without a loop.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Questions asking for "recommend a tool that does X" are considered off-topic. Check the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: @Isomane What's wrong with doing it in a loop?

Answer (score 1):

This should work on any POSIX shell:

```bash
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
numbers="104 101 108 108 111"
# Rely on word splitting here to break up the string                                                                                                                                                                                             
printf "$(printf '\%o' $numbers)\n"
```

The inner `printf` converts each decimal number to a base-8 octal one with a leading backslash, which the outer `printf` then displays as the corresponding character. Plus a newline for neatness.